# Assigning dynamic executed query to variables

Tags: sybase

Is there any way in SYBASE to store the values which is returned from (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) dynamic query to variables

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL
INTO x, y
```

Comment: You probably need to state which Sybase product as there are multiple (ASE, IQ, Anywhere) and their feature sets differ between products.

Comment: Thanks Rich
I'm using Anywhere platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but for what it's worth...
    BEGIN

```
     DECLARE x int;
     DECLARE y int;

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
     'SET x = 5';
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
     'SET y = 3';

     SELECT x,y;

END
```